# What is the -b+ sign in creating locale specific directories in android?

Tags: java, android, localization, android-resources

According to android documentation,

To add support for more locales, create additional directories inside res/. Each directory's name should adhere to the following format:

```
<resource type>-b+<language code>[+<country code>]
```

For eg.

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-b+es/
           strings.xml
       mipmap/
           country_flag.png
       mipmap-b+es+ES/
           country_flag.png
```

Can anybody say why the symbol is like this `-b+` ?
Just for educational purpose.

Link:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#CreateDirs

Comment: I would guess b stands for "bundle"

Comment: `According to android documentation ...` Can you post a link to such a documentation?

Comment: @Rotwang https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#CreateDirs

Comment: @jhamon Can take your word but can you say why it shoud be "bundle".Also why is +ve and -ve sign?

Comment: So, it is special for the `mipmaps` folder (which **you should not use** anyway, other than for the app icon). For strings it is (Spanish strings (es locale)) `/values-es/strings.xml`. And for drawables it is (Spanish icons (es locale)) `/drawable-es/flag.png`

Comment: may be related to the name used in java. Locale files are called ["Resources Bundle"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)

Comment: @Rotwang But there it is said that     values-b+es/
           strings.xml.It is not just for mipmap folder

Comment: Scroll down a few lines in the same document...

Comment: @Rotwang yes got your point.Still can you give your opinion on this symbol -b+.Why is it like this?Is there any link to any documentation?Guess android headquarters didnt just give this symbol out of thin air.

Comment: @Rotwang, it seems to be an optimization introduced in Android 7: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html#postN

Comment: @jhamon thanks being an amateur didnt know about that.Thanks very much.But still why the symbol is used?Once again thanks for your direction on the optimization part

Comment: @jhamon Uh... another **"CLEVER improvement"** by the mighty Google Team!!

Comment: This question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42937871/211292

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a BCP-47 Tag which is added from Java SE 7. It is a IETF Standard to understand the Locale internally and to support the extensions of locale. Thats why android is using values-b+

For more info: 
https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/extensions.html