# Android localization - How to use values folder -b qualifier

Tags: android, localization

android resources folder values. What is the values**-b** option i read about [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)?

What i want to do is have my app support two different languages, french and spanish. But i had a thought. it would be much more organized if instead of doing strings-es.xml and strings-fr.xml if i could do this:

```
values-es
     |
    Strings.xml

values-fr
     |
    Strings.xml
```

this way if there is any other things that should be localized they can easily go into the respective folders.  Is this possible ?

Comment: values-es and values-fr folders is the proper way to do this

Comment: what does the -b signify ?

Comment: @j2emanue I believe your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42937871/211292

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using '-b' is a newer way of supporting locales. You can support locales using the method you indicate above, but you can also support locales by putting them in directories like this:

```
values-b+es/strings.xml
values-b+fr/strings.xml
```

Answer (score 6):

The synax of -b+ allows you to include the script of the language, for languages that use multiple script like Serbian, whilst the old method don't allow this.

The default format that Android uses (as of 7.1) is as following:
`values-sr` is Serbian in the Cyrillic script
`values-b+sr+Latn` is Serbian in the Latin script

It is known as a BCP 47 language tag. [BCP 47 documentation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47)

Comment: Hello. I have an app translated into Serbian (latin). The string folder is renamed "values-b+sr+Latn" as you said. It is working correctly in my emulator but it is NOT working for my translator's phone. Both, he with his real device, and I with the Android emulator have choosen Serbian (Latin) as the language, but in his case the app is still displayed in English. Do you have any clue of what can be happening here? Thanks

Comment: @Ton This request Android 7.1 at minimum, which is a very old version by now, but we can't just assume the translator's phone isn't running older OS. There's a small risk that the translator runs a modified version of Android that modifies how it reads languages, breaking functions like these. Obviously make sure Serbian is placed at the top of all languages, and that the app's language isn't overriden anywhere. Since it is working on the emulator, I'm not sure why it wouldn't work on a real device. Have you tested it on your own device?